# Very Low quality Flag Disputed even question does not have enough information

Tags: support, review-queues, flags, specific-question

I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30212756/unable-to-use-cellcontentclick) as very low quality, but it was disputed.

I flagged this as Low Quality because the user didn't post any code, and without seeing code, in this specific post, its hard to provide any help.

How can this be disputed?

I am not asking about what is the difference between a Disputed flag vs. helpful/declined flags. My question is how this specific question not  Low Quality?

I already used my all votes for the day, that's why I flagged it.

Even Now, this flagged question removed from the Stack Overflow, so I believe my Flagged was correct, however for whatever reason it will be disputed, otherwise question was not deleted from SO.I agreed that I used VLQ flag instead of close vote, but my original intention now achieved ,"*THE CLEAN and NEAT SO*".

Comment: That's not *very* low quality, *very* low quality is "sdalfjasd;fljdsfndsaofsadjfo;asdjdf".  Just vote to close and move on.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables:- "sdalfjasd;fljdsfndsaofsadjfo;asdjdf" is Spam, not low quality

Comment: @Piyush - `"sdalfjasd;fljdsfndsaofsadjfo;asdjdf" is Spam, not low quality ` - completely incorrect.  Spam is a link where the poster has an undisclosed affiliation to the link.  You shouldn't have 8 Steward badges if you don't know this.

Comment: The question in question should have been reviewed as "Should be Improved", not flagged for closing IMHO. If it wasn't found in the review queue I'm guessing a simple comment requesting code would have sufficed.

Comment: @Dan The community cannot improve that question, only the author can, so marking it as NI is just wasting the time of all of the reviewers who will be shown that question.  It should *absolutely* be closed until such time as the author edits it enough for it to be answerable.

Comment: @servy maybe I'm mis-reading your comment (or vice versa). I suggested leaving a comment on the question to provide more information, not have the community improve it. That wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: @Dan You suggested marking it as "should be improved", which is indicating that the community should improve it, and that will push it into the help and improvement queue for community members to edit.  It will then sit there, festering, because there's no way for the community to edit it into shape, and everyone that sees it will have to skip it, repeatedly, until it ages out.  The alternative being to *correctly* act on the post in the triage queue and indicate that the community cannot salvage it.

Answer (score 6):

If the question doesn't have sufficient information to answer it then *vote to close it* for the most applicable reason.  The "doesn't contain a reproducible example" reason or unclear are the two most likely candidates for questions lacking sufficient information.

There's no reason for you to flag the post at all.

Comment: I already used my all votes for the day, thats why I flag it

Comment: @Piyush That's not a reason to use VLQ

Comment: @ bluefeet:- so what I need to do in this case, Just skip this question? or flag it so that MOD can see it

Comment: @Piyush VLQ means the post is so bad that it needs to be removed immediately. If you are using it because you ran out of close votes, then you're doing it wrong. That is an inappropriate use of those flags. And no, you don't flag it for a moderator - mods should not be used to perform actions that the community can handle.

Comment: @Piyush No, you should not flag for mod attention because you've run out of close votes.

Comment: So I need to skip it?

Comment: You can't vote to close it.  If you have nothing else to do then yes, move on.

Comment: @ bluefeet, Servy:- thanks....